# Create expression tree (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>) with property of entity (x.ID == 123)

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I use generic mode of function with a parameter as TEntity
for example TEntity is Person

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I need generate an Expression Tree like the following (automaticaly):

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> :
          x=> x.ID = 123 && x.Name="AAA" && x.Family="BBB"
```

for return type of below method

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> SearchExpression()
{
    HERE !!!
}
```

Can anyone help me for this purpose ?

Comment: TEntity is simple class (my DTO) like Person

Comment: So, you want to filter class which is *like* Person by properties of Person?

Comment: I want to create an expression tree like this "x=> x.ID = 123 && x.Name="AAA" && x.Family="BBB" so I need to filter on properties of TEntity (x is Person)

Comment: @user3432343 But where are those sample values (i.e. 123, "AAA", "BBB") taken from? I assume you don't know the structure of your class at design time (otherwise that'd be pretty pointless), so what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: (i.e. 123, "AAA", "BBB") No problem I have it I need only Expression Tree no problem with this values

Comment: @user3432343 and how are we to use those values in the expression if you're unwilling to share any details about how those are to be obtained?

Comment: my problem is left expression x.ID , Expression left = ???; 
                Expression right = Expression.Constant(value); // I have this value, you can use above sample here Expression.Constant(123)
                Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

Comment: @user3432343 But how do you know that the first property is an int, so it can be matched with `Expression.Constant(123)`? If you know it, then the whole concept is pointless - you don't need to generate this at runtime; if you don't, you mind end up comparing `SqlConnection` to `123`. Could you share what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I have tuple for that List<Tuple<string, string, Type>> , // Item1 : PropertyName (ID) , // Item2 : value of PropertyName as text ("123") , // Item3 : Type of Property (System.Int32) then I use var value = Convert.ChangeType(Item2,Item3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description / comments, the following should work for you:

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> SearchExpression()
{
    ConstantExpression[] expectedValues = Your_Magic_Method_Of_Obtaining_Expected_Values();

    var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TEntity));

    var comparisonExpression = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()
                                              .Select((info, i) => Expression.Equal(
                                                                      Expression.Property(entity, info),
                                                                      expectedValues[i]))
                                              .Aggregate(Expression.And);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(comparisonExpression, entity);
}
```

Comment: very handy code for creating a simple predicate expression deserializer: https://github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/config/blob/master/My%20Documents/LINQPad%20Queries/Reflection/ExpressionDeserialization.linq

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> Filters { get; set; } = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>();
```

implement IQueryable

```
    if (xxx.Filters != null && xxx.Filters.Any())
    {
        foreach (var filter in xxx.Filters)
        {
            list = list.Where(filter);
        }
    }
```

set filters

```
    xxx.Filters.Add(x => x.YourProperty1Name.Contains("98"));
    xxx.Filters.Add(x => x.YourProperty2Name.Equals("abc"));
```